# How can I generalize a vector-matrix-vector product into a vector?

Tags: matrices, vectors, products, kronecker-product, vectorization

I've been trying to generalize a vector-matrix-vector product that represents the $i$th element of a vector $v$, but I can't figure out how to put it into a concise form.

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the vector in question. Let $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $R \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ be matrices. I also define $k_i \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times m}$ to be the $i$th row of $K$. The $i$th element of the vector $v$ is
\begin{equation}
 v_i = k_i R k_i^T.
\end{equation}

How can I write the whole vector $v$ in terms of $K$ and $R$? I also suspect it could require vectorization or Kronecker products.

The closest I think I've gotten is something like this:
\begin{equation}
K[\underbrace{R,R,\ldots,R}_{\text{repeated }n \text{ times,}\\ \text{so } m \times nm}]\underbrace{\text{vec}(K^T)}_{nm \times 1},
\end{equation}
where vec$(\cdot)$ represents vectorization, i.e., the stacking of vector columns. However, this only works if I could somehow keep just the diagonal blocks of $K[R,R,\ldots,R]$ so that it becomes
\begin{equation*}
 K[R,R,\ldots,R] = \begin{bmatrix}
                    k_1 R & & & \\
                     & k_2R & & \\
                     & & \ddots &  \\
                     & &  & k_nR \\
                   \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
Then I would have
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 k_1 R & & & \\
 & k_2R & & \\
 & & \ddots &  \\
 & &  & k_nR \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 k_1^T \\
 k_2^T \\
 \vdots  \\
 k_n^T \\
 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Could you provide some context for this, specifically about for $K$ and $R$? You could just take $[0,\ldots,0,\underbrace{1}_{i},0,\ldots,0]I_n \vec{v}=v_i$

Comment: @Chickenmancer I need to calculate the whole vector $v$ in a recursive algorithm. At each iteration I am given $K$ and $R$. $K$ is general and has no specific properties, but $R$ is a symmetric covariance matrix. I could go about it by calculating each element $v_i=k_iRk_i^T$, I but this could become tedious if the dimension $n$ grows.

Comment: It is inevitable to compute each $k_i\,R\,k_i^T$, in my answer, I am just presenting a more compact way to represent this vector as an algebraic equation.

Comment: For computational efficiency, you can do what you have proposed: compute $B=K\,R$, then perform each dot product between each row of $B$ and the corresponding column of $K^T$.

Comment: @DanielCunha I'd prefer not to compute each $k_iRk_i^T$. I accepted your answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that:

$$\boxed{v = \text{diag}(K\,R\,K^T)}$$

---

We can define a $3rd$ order tensor $T$, such that:

$$T_{ijk} = \delta_{ij}\,\delta_{ik}$$

(this is not Einstein notation, so there is no summation over the $i$-index)

---

Therefore, $T_{ijk} = A^{(i)}_{jk}$, where the matrices $A^{(i)}$ are given by:

$$A^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & ... & 0\\
0 & 0 & ... & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A^{(2)} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & ... & 0\\
0 & 1 & ... & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A^{(m)} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & ... & 0\\
0 & 0 & ... & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

---

Using this tensor, we have that:

$$\boxed{v_i = T_{ijk}\,K_{km}\,R_{mn}\,K_{jn}}$$

(now it is [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation))

---

Alternatively:

$$\boxed{v = T : \left[K \cdot R \cdot K^T\right]}$$

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I didn't try this. Seems simple in hindsight!